# react what is the esiest way to acces the locale

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

in my react app I set the locale like this:

```
const store = createStore(
    combineReducers({
        i18n: i18nReducer
    }),
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
);
syncTranslationWithStore(store)
store.dispatch(loadTranslations(translationsObject));
store.dispatch(setLocale('de'));
```

what would be a good and easy method to check which language is set?

I tried this:

```
store.dispatch(getLocale());
```

But thats not working.

Thanks for your help

Comment: This is what a "selector" is for in Redux. You'll find more information here: http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ComputingDerivedData.html :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should connect your react component to Redux state using [connect](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) and map state property indicating locale to prop, something like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        locale: state.i18n.locale
    }
};

const connectedSomeComponent= connect(
    mapStateToProps
)(someComponent);
```

then you can simply use `locale` prop in `someComponent`.

You can also access store state directly using [getState](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html#getstate) so if you'd like to access state property outside react component you can do something like this:

```
const myState = store.getState();
const locale = myState.i18n.locale;
```

Comment: Thanks, the first solution is not working, do I have to import connect?. Second one looks better and works. I added this code: 
`
    if (locale == "de"){
        store.dispatch(setLocale('en'));
    } else {
        store.dispatch(setLocale('de'));
    } `

I can change the language once, but not several times. What could be the problem?

Comment: Yes, you have to import `connect`. Please check this docs how to use Redux with React: http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html 
`What could be the problem?` - I can't answer since it depends on your application code details. Besides, it is not directly realed to this SO question. Please create new SO question with whole relevant code